# Can I highlight staff names in a google sheet based on who has filled out a form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I frequently have to confirm if all of my staff have filled out a google form and what their answer is to RSVP for an event. I want to continue to prompt those that have not filled out the form, or follow up with staff that say they can't make it. I'm a beginner at google sheets formulas and have been able to use some queries. I also often have people fill out the form wrong and won't put their full name or some other issue, causing only partial matches.

Right now, we just manually go through the google sheet and check off staff that have filled out the form. I tried to do a query, but had difficulty utilizing it due to partial matches. Here is an image of an example of the sheet:

[image]

I can share the actual sheet. I deleted the formula I was working with, but would love some help in how to match names ot a partial formula to determine if they filled out the form.

Comment: Are you able to share a sample spreadsheet so we can help you debug? Most likely there are some formulas/conditional formatting we can apply to help you stay on top of it, but it'll still require some manual checking.

Comment: Thanks! here is the sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11lm-ytkF5IcnFdNa1QuZ-QU6QfbtHftxHokSaCc2sp8/edit#gid=661215026.

Comment: I think a conditional formatting formula would help. I have text in column B and I want any given cell to change color if there is any cell in column G with matching or partial matching text. I've tried some =IF formulas but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you make the spreadsheet public (ie anyone with a link can access)?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11lm-ytkF5IcnFdNa1QuZ-QU6QfbtHftxHokSaCc2sp8/edit?usp=sharing Here is the sheet shared to view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for sharing the sample sheet. I made a copy in the sheet where I added a conditional formatting rule that will highlight the cells in column B if there is an exact or partial match in column G. For the partial match, the search string (ie the values in column B) need to appear in column G either at the beginning, middle, or end of the user submitted string. For example, the cell for "Samantha Gold" will highlight in column B if a user enters any of the following:

- Samantha Gold
- Samantha Gold1
- Samantha Gold18276348362872362837
- 12379287319279Samantha Gold
- sjdfiojdijfSamantha Goldskaldjslkdjsl
  For safety, I'm also making the match essentially case insensitive by forcing everything to lowercase. It will not match if the user submits something like "Sam Gold".

Just to explain the formatting rule: `=arrayformula(isnumber(match("*"&lower(B5)&"*",lower($G$5:$G$8),0)))`
Conditional formatting rules must always evaluate to `true`/`false`, I saw you were playing around with a vlookup, but that won't work as a formatting rule because it may not necessarily evaluate to a boolean. Working from the inside out:

- `lower(string)` converts the  strings to lower case, just to avoid any discrepancies with upper/lower case values
- `match(text, search_range, match_type)` searches the provided search_range for the given text. A match type of `0` means it's looking for an "exact" match, but because we add the wildcards to the beginning and end of the string it's really looking for that exact text somewhere in the middle of the cells within the search range (there are other match types, but they are almost never what you need)
- match returns the row number where the match is found, but because conditional formatting rules must evaluate to true/false, we wrap it in a `isnumber(value)`, which evaluates to true for numbers and evaluates to false for everything else (ie if no match is found, it'll throw an error, which translates to a string).
- `arrayformula` is a little more complicated, but it basically is necessary for the `lower` method to work. Normally, `lower` only works on a single cell at a time, but with `arrayformula` it's able to accept a full range of cells.

(Find more information on all of these on the [official docs](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en).)

All that being said, I would definitely recommend using email address if possible to do some of this conditional formatting. Email Addresses tend to be entered in more faithfully and they usually serve better as a unique ID (in the event that some people have the same name or go by the same name).

Comment: Thank you so much, Miguel! This is fantastic and I really appreciate your explanation. Definitely will help me improve my sheets skills overall! I'll consider using email addresses moving forward.